Why is the below piece of code giving error when I add console log line and working fine if I remove it?
The code below works fine if I remove the console log line but not with it
function gcd(a, b) {
    while (b !== 0) {
        console.log(a,b)
        [a, b] = [b, a % b];
    }
    return a;
}

console.log(gcd(4,96))

The error I am getting
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '96')
    at gcd (C:\Users\Rajashekar\example.js:332:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rajashekar\example.js:337:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47


It has to do with javascript automatic semicolon insertion.
If a line starts with one of the below special character
(, [, `, +, / - then the previous line should end with a semicolon.
This line [a, b] = [b, a % b]; starts with [ but in the previous line is console.log does not end with ;
In your case you need to add a semicolon like console.log(a,b);

Yeah. If I add a semicolon it is working fine. But where did you find this information? Is there anything on official documentation about it?

@RajashekarReddy this might be what you are looking for: ECMAScript Specification
